# Google sheets web app blocked by CORS when trying to send a get request on the front-end

Tags: google-apps-script, frontend, cors, httprequest

I'm trying to make a google web app, but when I to send a get request, it gives me an error saying `"_ has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."`
Javascript (front-end only):

```js
fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

App Script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
    // get spreadsheet
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataCollection');
    const max = sheet.getRange("F1").getValue();

    // get data and sort by amount
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= max; i++) {data.push({name: sheet.getRange("B" + i).getValue(), data: sheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue()});}
    data.sort((a, b) => (a.data > b.data) && -1 || 1);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Currently, the deployment of the web app is set to execute as myself and anyone has access, and my webpage is static.

The web app works perfectly fine when I tested the code, but CORS blocks the request when I send it through my webpage. I've tried multiple solutions that worked for other people, but I kept getting the same result.

Solutions I've tried:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: response => console.log(response)
});
```

- I tried adding `redirect: "follow"` to the fetch which did nothing
- I tried adding `mode: "no-cors"` to the fetch which returned an empty response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that in your Javascript, no request header is required to be used, because of the GET method. And, I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.
- And, in order to retrieve the values from your Web Apps as a JSON object, how about modifying `.then(response => {console.log(response);})` to `then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res))`?
- And, when I saw your Google Apps Script, I thought that the process cost will become high because `getValue()` is used in a loop.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataCollection');
  const max = sheet.getRange("F1").getValue();
  const data = sheet.getRange("A1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().splice(0, max).map(([data, name]) => ({ name, data }));
  data.sort((a, b) => (a.data > b.data) && -1 || 1);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

- In your script, it seems that the event object `e` is not used.

##### Javascript side:

```js
fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec") // Please set your Web Apps URL.
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res));
```

#### Note:

- When I tested your showing script, I confirmed the same issue related to `CORS`. And, when my proposed script is used, I confirmed that the issue was removed.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- **By the way, from your Javascript, in this case, it supposes that your Web Apps is deployed as "Execute as: Me" and "Who has access to the app: Anyone". Please be caraful about this.**

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)